# Using Regex to filter word in Java

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a message that comes into the Android Device as text message which I read when it comes in like this `Your OTP verification code is 5M67BX` the `OTP code` isn't fixed. It varies, if it were to be like that I'll just use a `Regex` `Pattern` of `([0-9]){1}([A-Z]){1}([0-9]){2}([A-Z]){1}` But, it isn't always like that. Sometimes all numbers. If you can share `Pattern` to filter the code out in `Java` would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is it fixed length? Would simply `([A-Z0-9]){6}` work?

Comment: Yes, it's fixed length

Comment: @ItuokeAjanlekoko is gla3dr regex is working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is always a fixed length (6) and always at the end of the String, you could do:

```
String s = "Your OTP verification code is 5M67BX";
String otpCode = s.substring(s.length() - 6);
```

Edit: With Regex this time...

```
String s = "Your OTP verification code is 5M67BX";  
String s2 = "Your updated OTP code is YW32R2 for phone verification";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z0-9]){6}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
m = p.matcher(s2);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Which outputs...

```
5M67BX
YW32R2
```

Comment: Yeah. But, there are two versions of the text one ends with it and the other doesn't. So, I'll need to go with regex. Anyway, good one. Thanks

Comment: Could you show me an example of the String that doesn't end with the OTP code?

Comment: `Your updated  OTP code is 5M67BX for phone verification`

Comment: Edited answer above to include a java solution using regex (from gla3dr).